# Where should I go to find Virgin Booty?

Tags: kingdom-of-loathing

After arriving on the Poop Deck, I was given the option of taking the helm and steering the ship. Where should I go?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PS: Spoilers follow.

As per the wiki, I'd recommend going to either (59,10), (86,40), or (48,47).
These coordinates give you the [El Vibrato power sphere](http://kol.coldfront.net/thekolwiki/index.php/El_Vibrato_power_sphere), which can (after a lot of work) yield a new familiar, new zone, etc. 
Apparently all other coordinates are all the same and will give you [Ocean Treasure](http://kol.coldfront.net/thekolwiki/index.php/Ocean_Treasure).

It seems you're a new player, so I would think that El Vibrato would be best for you.